# ITIN requirements

Tags: social-security

I came to US this year in Feb. I have SSN now. Should I apply for my dependent (kid and wife) ITIN now or later?

1. I was going through SSA site, and in order to apply ITIN, believe my tax return form is required. Is that so?
2. I have not filed for US tax return till now. Kindly advise.
3. Also what all documents are required for my dependents to get ITIN?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: https://redbus2us.com/file-taxes-us-h4-visa-dependents-apply-itin-number/ according to this site, you'll apply using form w-7 when you submit your tax return next year.

Answer (score 2):

They will apply for ITINs by filing W-7 together with filing tax returns (you will file this year's tax returns early next year). Only under certain special situations (which likely don't apply to them) are they allowed to get ITINs separately from tax filing.

p.s. ITINs are issued by IRS and are not related to SSA

Comment: This is correct - I am on H-1B and my wife is on dependent H-4. We applied for her ITIN at the same time as I filed my taxes so that I could file as 'Married-Filing-Jointly'. You'll need to submit copies of passports & visas along with the ITIN applications.